# why HashSet extends AbstractSet and implements Set?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

`public class HashSet<E>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, Serializable`

Why HashSet extends AbstractSet and implements Set, as AbstractSet already implements Set?

Answer (score 0):

A `HashSet` is a `Set`. It implements the contract defined by the `Set` interface. Therefore it's useful to make it clear that it implements that interface, without having to check the class hierarchy.

The fact that it extends `AbstractSet<E>` is just an implementation detail. It might stop extending `AbstractSet` in a future Java version (though probably not very likely), but it would always implement `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it will work properly without implementing the `set` interface. But it is done for making the code more readable so that any programmer can understand it properly without seeing the full hierarchy of class. And also for minimizing the risk can be happen in future (if `HashSet` does not implement the `AbstructSet`, although it is not very likely).